# Are there any historic examples of breaking the one-time pad because of a careless key re-use? i.e simple attack on a multiple-time pad?

Tags: one-time-pad, classical-cipher, xor

It doesn't have be using a truly random key, (it could be the Enigma) but the attack must be based on XORing two parts of ciphertext.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venona_project

Comment: The Wiki page gives a highly significant real example. But how "simple" was that attack? It would be fine if there exists a paper detailing how one should advantageously proceed in practice to deal with a two-time pad IMHO.

Comment: @Mok-KongShen Solving it using a modern computer is easy. Doing it manually is pretty impressive.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I am an ignorant. Could you please give a link to a good computer code that decrypts two messages that were encypted with the same one-time pad?

Comment: @Mok-KongShen Such a program can not exist *for general messages* (on the scale of the halting problem). You simply XOR two ciphertexts and then have the XOR of the plaintexts. Getting the original messages from that depends entirely on the kind of message, the language, etc.